# Intermediate Value Property on a uniformly continuous function

Tags: uniform-continuity

Is a uniformly continuous function on  [a,\infty) consume Intermediate Value Property?

Answer (score 1):

A uniformly continuous function is continuous. Consequently, since you have a continuous function in a closed set, you can apply the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

You can treat limits at both infinities, say $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ as a point, and apply IVT.